# unable to use pytesseract on mac, after downloading tesseract through homebrew in terminal

Tags: ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

the code i would like to run:

import cv2
import pytesseract

img = cv2.imread("the path to the png file")
print(pytesseract.image_to_string(img))

the answer i get:

TesseractNotFoundError: tesseract is not installed or it's not in your PATH. See README file for more information.

Answer (score -1):

have you put this variable :

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = "/usr/local/bin/tesseract"

I use pytesseract on Mac.
here is an example of code :
"
`import cv2`
`import pytesseract`
`from pytesseract import Output`

`pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = "/usr/local/bin/tesseract`
`custom_config = r'-c tessedit_char_blacklist=|[]{}?!&§()$*:ùûÿ --psm 6 --oem 3'`

## custom config allows me to remove unwanted characters

`test=path+"image.png"`
`img = cv2.imread(test)`

`d=pytesseract.image_to_data(img, lang='fra',config=custom_config,output_type='data.frame').dropna()`

## output_type = 'data.frame' to use pandas to process the data

`test1 = pytesseract.image_to_string(img ,lang = 'fra', config = custom_config)`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).